# Automatic Micra moving on its own & idle speed

Tags: nissan, automatic-transmission

Just bought a used Nissan Micra (automatic transmission).

When I depress the brake and change into D or R to move off, and then let go of the brake, the car starts moving off slowly.

Only had one other automatic car before and it didn't move until I pressed the accelerator.

In the manual it mentions that the cold-start idle speed is high and therefore caution should be exercised.

Does the above explain what I am experiencing ie use caution because the car moves on its own?!

Or is the car faulty?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not uncommon on automatic trans equipped vehicles. Since you didn't state how fast the car in moving it is hard to say if yours is normal. A slight creep forward is normal (5KMH) moving at anything faster  is a problem. If it is moving faster than that the idle may be set slightly high which would cause the car to move while in drive.

Comment: Thanks Mikes, yes its just a very slight creep forward (or backwards).